# Can't add description of customization parameters in Edit Packaged IP of Xilinx Vivado

Tags: fpga, xilinx, vivado

Settings: Vivado 2023.1 on Windows 10.

The customization parameters were added after Create and Package New IP wizard. The Description field of all the newly added customization parameters is always blank. I filled up the Tooltip field in Edit IP Parameter dialog as shown below, but the text just does not show up in the Description after I click OK. What am I missing to set up the Description of a new customization parameter in Edit Packaged IP of Xilinx Vivado? I have read document UG1118 but it doesn't help with this issue.

Vivado package IP tab:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. In **PROJECT MANAGER > Package IP > Customization Parameters**, select the parameter you wish to edit.
2. Edit **PROJECT MANAGER > IP Parameter Properties* > Description:**

*To the left of the **Package IP** window, there is **Sources** on top and **IP Parameters Properties** below.

I had problems finding this too as I would expect it in the Edit IP Parameter window as well...